# How do I get summations to display correctly?

Tags: support, mathjax

On Windows 7 with Firefox 52.0 I get only the bottom half of summation symbols displayed.

As an example, I provide a small screenshot below the following link. Does anyone know what I need to do to get summations to display correctly?

[Analysing an optics model in discrete and continuous forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/analysing-an-optics-model-in-discrete-and-continuous-forms)

[image]

Comment: It works for me. Maybe try to refresh the page and possibly clear your browser cache. Can you see other sumamtion symbols like $$\sum_{i=1}^n x^2 $$

Comment: Try right-clicking on one of those formulas, which brings up a little MathJax menu.  Under "Math Settings" you will see a sub-menu that allows choice of "Math Renderer".  Report which one you have in effect for Math.SE (the choice for Meta.Math.SE is an independent setting, as it goes site by site).  I have the choice "Common HTML" in my settings for Math.SE ("HTML-CSS" for Meta), but you should try others to see if one is more satisfactory than your current one.

Comment: Changing "Math Renderer" to "Common HTML" did the trick. Others did work but I guess "Common HTML" being second from the top menu item is a good choice. I like it anyway. I would have happily accepted the answer. This is the second question I have asked, and both have been perfectly well answered in a comment. Just sayin'. Thank you hardmath (and quid).

Comment: It may be the same question as this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12179/442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the OP'S Comment, experimenting with the various Math Renderer options in the right-click MathJax menu resolved this problem satisfactorily.

Choosing among the Math Renderer options is made by cookies on a site by site basis.  Thus I can have different options for Math.SE, Meta.Math.SE, and SciComp.SE.

Some renderers are more robust and others faster in keeping up during lengthy Edit sessions, so prolific Users are helped by these menu choices.